# How to remove quantity from cart page in WooCommerce for downloadable items

Tags: woocommerce

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help with this. As I have many virtual/ downloadable items in my Woocommerce shopping page, is there a way to disable, or make the quantity field disappear, entirely but only for those types of items? I have had several occurrences where customers bought multiple of something that was digital, and since that didnt make much sense because they could download it multiple times, I wound up manually refunding the extra. To avoid this extra work, can qty get turned off if the downloadable checkbox is ticked on the product page, or something like that? And it just keeps the default qty of 1 during checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
function hide_downloadable_quantity_field_cart( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['data'] ) && $cart_item['data']->is_downloadable() ) {
        $product_quantity = '';
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'hide_downloadable_quantity_field_cart', 10, 3 );
```

It should remove the quantity field completely for downloadable items in the cart.

Comment: I added it to my theme's function file and checked an item, but it still had the qty field.